# Creating a function using the binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to use a function to  find a  number in an array using the binary search. The code runs in visual studio community but does not work in code blocks. It just shows  found.Would appreciate if some could point out why it's not working. This is the function

```
void sort(int array[7],int num)
     {
        int left=0,right=7;
        while (left<=right)
         { 
          int mid = (left+right)/2;
          if(array[mid]==num)
           {
            cout<<"found";
            break;
           }
          else if(num<array[mid])
            right = mid-1;
          else 
             left = mid+1;
      }
      if(left > right) cout<<"not found";
    }
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: This implementation should fail in both IDEs/ text editors. `right` with a value of 7 won't work as the last index within the array is 6 as array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: Snark: function `sort` has an unusual name if its purpose is to search. Could lead to confused people and confused people drop bugs into the code.

Comment: I highly recommend using `binary_search` or `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` rather than writing your own.  These standard functions have already been tested (debugged).

Answer (score 1):

When you write, `int array[7]`, then you create an array which can be indexed `0..6`. Therefore, you should use `right = 6`.

Also, be very careful when you write `right = mid - 1` or `left = mid + 1`. You need to be sure that the new values are within `0..6`. E.g., `left == 0, right == 1, mid == 0` - after this, you say `right = - 1`. That's not ok, you need boundary checks.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out